# UPDATE col based on GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-update

I have one table

```
id |  title  | ...
––----------------
 1 |  test A | ...
 2 |  test C | ...
 3 |  test B | ...
 4 |  test C | ...
 5 |  test B | ...
 6 |  test X | ...
```

And I want to add a column based on GROUP BY query : `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY title`

```
id |  title  | group_id (int)
––--------------------------
 1 |  test A | 1
 2 |  test C | 2
 3 |  test B | 3
 4 |  test C | 2
 5 |  test B | 3
 6 |  test X | 4
```

`group_id` doesn't need to be significant, it just have to be the same value on the row which have the same `title` value and different from the other.

How can I do this ?

Thanks.

PS: Sorry for my English, I'm french.

Comment: If "*`group_id` doesn't have to be significant*", why not `UPDATE table SET group_id = title`?

Comment: Why? If it's indexed, what does one gain from making it an insignificant integer?

Comment: It doesn't need to be insignificant integer. But I need a integer for a future use.

Comment: So just interpret the bytes as an integer?  I really don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.  Perhaps an instance of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/161492)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well given you alter the table and add the new column ParentID ?
Something like

```
UPDATE ATable t
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      Title, 
      MIN(ID) AS ID
    FROM ATable
    GROUP BY Title
  ) m ON t.Title = m.Title
SET t.ParentID = m.ID
```